# Schedule a job to run every 5 mins only on a particular day in python

Tags: python, scheduler, schedule

I want to run a cron job for every 5 mins only on a particular day of the week. I am using python schedule library and I can do these jobs individually. But how do I club them?

code

```
import schedule

def check():
    print('Checking')

schedule.every(10).monday.do(check)
while True: 
    # Checks whether a scheduled task is pending to run or not 
    schedule.run_pending()
```

This gives an error `IntervalError: Use mondays instead of monday` when I try with mondays, I get an error `AttributeError: 'Job' object has no attribute 'mondays'` can someone help me with this.

Comment: What do you mean by "club them"?

Comment: I want to run the job every monday, every 5 mins

Comment: You are repeating what's already in the question rather than clarifying the weird choice of words I asked about.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the `schedule` package supports combinations of different time units the way you want. You can achieve what you want doing something like:

```
import schedule
import time
import datetime

def job():
    if datetime.datetime.today().weekday() == 0:
        print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(5).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, though.

Comment: what does `datetime.today().weekday()` do ?

Comment: @cvg It is just checking: 'Today is Monday or not'

Answer (score -1):

Did you try with "time"?

```
import time
...

schedule.every().monday.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: Thank you, but with this I am not able to run for today, which is a monday. next run is coming to be for next monday